# How to access forward declaration in C++ class?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

The following code works, but it is not very readable to have methods separated from each state of this state machine:

```
struct Base {
    virtual Base* next() = 0;
};

struct StateA : public Base {
    Base* next();
};

struct StateB : public Base {
    Base* next();
};

StateA stateA;
StateB stateB;

Base* StateA::next() {
    return &stateB;
}

Base* StateB::next() {
    return &stateA;
}
```

I would rather prefer to have this structure, unfortunately, I don't know if it is possible in C++ to foward declare `stateA` and `stateB`:

```
struct Base {
    virtual Base* next() = 0;
};

struct StateA : public Base {
    Base* next() { return &stateB; }
};

struct StateB : public Base {
    Base* next() { return &stateA; }
};

StateA stateA;
StateB stateB;
```

Is it possible to keep the implementation of `StateX` along with their declaration?

I have tried to trick the compiler with this, but as guessed, it doesn't build:

```
struct Base {
    virtual Base* next() = 0;
};

struct StateA;
struct StateB;

extern StateA *stateAptr;
extern StateB *stateBptr;

struct StateA : public Base {
    Base* next() { return stateBptr; }
};

struct StateB : public Base {
    Base* next() { return stateAptr; }
};

StateA stateA;
StateB stateB;
StateA *stateAptr = &stateA;
StateB *stateBptr = &stateB;
```

Comment: "it is not very readable to have methods separated from each state of this state machine".  Q: Are you saying that you don't like a declaration in one place (e.g. a header file) and a definition in a separate place (e.g. .c or .cpp implementation files)?  Q: What exactly are your questions about/problems with "extern"?  Does this link help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1433387/421195

Comment: I have a state machine with several states. Each state have several methods (entry, exit, stay). Having each implementation located in each State is convenient. Also these states can stay in a single cpp file since the interface is a global StateMachine that use all states.  @paulsm4 does it answer your Q?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `extern` is responsible for forward variable declarations. But it's can be used before their types are defined. You can split member function declarations and definitions.

```
struct Base {
    virtual Base* next() = 0;
};

struct StateA : public Base {
    Base* next();
};

struct StateB : public Base {
    Base* next();
};

StateB stateB;
StateA stateA;

Base* StateA::next() { return &stateB; }
Base* StateB::next() { return &stateA; }
```

Or update your trick for using `Base*` pointers.

```
struct Base {
    virtual Base* next() = 0;
};

extern Base *stateAptr;
extern Base *stateBptr;

struct StateA : public Base {
    Base* next() { return stateBptr; }
};

struct StateB : public Base {
    Base* next() { return stateAptr; }
};

StateA stateA;
StateB stateB;
Base *stateAptr = &stateA;
Base *stateBptr = &stateB;
```

But it does not improve readability in comparison with the first code, and conflicts with your sentence *"it is not very readable"*.